# sugueを使わずにURLを受け渡す方法を、教えてください

Tags: swift2, xcode7

Xcode 7.3で、storyboardを使わずにtableviewをクリックすると、DetailViewController.swiftへ画面遷移するソースを書いています。

CustomViewController.entryにself.List[indexPath.row]の値を代入したいのですが、cannnot assign value of type self.List[indexPath.row]とエラーがでて、代入できません。

self.List[indexPath.row]にはURLが入っております。

sugueを使わずにCustomViewControllerにURLを受け渡す方法を、教えてください。

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let CustomViewController = DetailViewController()
    CustomViewController.entry = self.List[indexPath.row]
    parent!.navigationController!.pushViewController(detailViewController , animated: true)
}
```

Comment: コードを記載する際は、コードを選択して`{}`ボタンを押すとハイライトされます。ご活用ください。

Answer (score 0):

> CustomViewController.entryにself.List[indexPath.row]の値を代入したいのですが、cannnot assign value of type self.List[indexPath.row]とエラーがでて、代入できません。

そのエラーは、型の不一致を示しています。`CustomViewController.entry`の型と、`self.List[indexPath.row]`の型が一致していないので、代入できないというメッセージです。
Swiftは型に厳密な言語で、例えば、`Double`型の変数に、`Float`型の値を代入することさえできません。可能なのは、親クラスの型の変数に、子クラスのインスタンスを代入する、アップキャストと、Typealiasした型で、実体は同じものの間の代入、そして`Any`型変数への代入に限られます。

> self.List[indexPath.row]にはURLが入っております。

URLとだけ書かれても、それが文字列型なのか、`NSURL`のインスタンスなのかわからないと、先に進めません。そして、問題点は、「sugue（ママ）を使わずにURLを受け渡す方法」と、直接関係ありません。（`sugue`→`segue`）

Comment: おっしゃるとおり、entryの型を間違えて指定していたので、正しい配列の型を作り直したら、無事にできました。sugueではなく、segueでしたね。早々の回答ありがとうございました。